# Exclude packages from node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I want to exclude 3 packages from node modules. currently I am doing it as

```
const jsRules = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(some-package|engine.io-client|socket.io-client)\/).*/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }
};
```

but they are not getting excluded.

If I exclude entire node_modules and then include the required ones(as in below code), then it is working.

```
const jsRules = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }
};

const jsRulesNodeModules = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  include: [
    /node_modules\/some-package/,
    /node_modules\/engine.io-client/,
    /node_modules\/socket.io-client/
  ],
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }
};
```

can someone help in excluding those three packages from node_modules as first case itself (without using two rules as in second case)

Comment: Did you see this? https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#external-limitations

Comment: I have used regular expression ```exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(some-package|engine.io-client|socket.io-client)\/).*/``` but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try excluding like this as mentioned in [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/)

```
 exclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/lib1"),...other excluded libraries]
```